# Javascript text engine types all the letters at once instead of on command

Tags: javascript, html, text, keydown, document.write

I am making a text engine in javascript where the user types a series of letters, and those letters get printed out on the screen. I am currently using an `if` statement for each individual key. Why do all the letters automatically appear at once? Is there a more efficient way to do this only using javascript?

I have already tried

```js
if(keydown = "e"){
document.write("e");
}
```

```js
document.clear();
if(keydown="a"){
    document.write("a");
}
if(keydown="b"){
    document.write("b");
}
document.clear();
if(keydown="c"){
    document.write("c");
}
if(keydown="d"){
    document.write("d");
}
// and so on...
```

I expected for each key that the user presses to appear on the screen, but instead all of them appear at once without any user interaction. You do not need to answer this if you can tell me a more efficient way to make a text engine in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Change the single `=` to double `==` or triple `===`.

```js
if (keydown = "a") {
    document.write("a");
}
```

to

```js
if (keydown === "a") {
    document.write("a");
}
```

If you'd like to learn more, check: [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. However, this doesn't seem to be working either. Now nothing happens at all. Thanks for trying!

Comment: That works, but there are two problems: 1. You have to actually type the letters into a box, and secondly, when you delete it types "backspace".

Comment: You can bind the event to any object in your dom. Its about the principle, it works, you can do the rest.